# Jersey error while downloading file from restful web services

Tags: java, web-services, file, rest, jersey

My application is accessing a restful web service using client which returns me a file.
When i test this on my local environment everything works like a charm, however when i try to access the same web service deployed on an other environment it gives me the below error:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.meltwater.mpress.ws.model.converter.ResponseStatusConverter, and Java type class com.meltwater.mpress.ws.model.converter.ResponseStatusConverter, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found
```

Not sure why this is happening, had this been because of some code problem i believe this would not have worked on my local as well.

Any help in this regards would be helpful.

Thanks

Vaibhav

Comment: can you post the client code and if you can the response headers? I think that you are trying to get an xml response but your server is responding with text/html.

Comment: my bad i am modifying the question there is some strange error on web service side which throws an exception and wen that exception is treated in the client it throws this exception. modifying the error stack. apologies